# collection with type tagging not recognised in extension method

Tags: scala, collections, types

I want to use [tagged types](https://gist.github.com/milessabin/89c9b47a91017973a35f) to indicate whether a collection is sorted or not. For example:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

class Tagger[U] {
  def apply[T](t : T) : T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
}
def tag[U] = new Tagger[U]

trait Sorted
```

Now I want to define a method that requires that a collection is sorted:

```
implicit final class RichIndexedSeq[A, CC <: IndexedSeq[A]](val sq: CC) 
  extends AnyVal {

  /** Nearest percentile (rounded index, no interpolation). */
  def percentile(n: Int)(implicit sorted: CC <:< Tagged[Sorted]): A = 
    sq((sq.size * n - 50) / 100)
}
```

I would prefer to keep the tag check as implicit evidence parameter, because there will be going other methods into `RichIndexedSeq` which do not have that constraint.

I must be making something wrong, though. I expected this to work:

```
val x = Vector.fill(10)((math.random * 100).toInt)
val y = tag[Sorted](x.sorted)
```

But it doesn't:

```
y.percentile(50)

<console>:44: error: value percentile is not a member of 
                     @@[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],Sorted]
              y.percentile(50)
                ^
```

The problem must originate in the extension method indirection, because this works:

```
implicitly[Vector[Int] @@ Sorted <:< Tagged[Sorted]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the ScalaC bug (?) with the type schizophrenia (method `percentile` in stew's and Keniji's answer cannot be declared to return `A`), I ended up giving up having the input collection type at hand. This is ok here, because I don't build a new collection in this particular method:

```
implicit class RichSortedIndexedSeq[A](val sq: IndexedSeq[A] @@ Sorted) 
  extends AnyVal {

  def percentile(n: Int): A = sq((sq.size * n - 50) / 100)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```scala
implicit final class RichIndexedSeq[A, CC[_] <: IndexedSeq[_]](val sq: CC[A] @@ Sorted)
  extends AnyVal {

  def percentile(n: Int) = 
    sq((sq.size * n - 50) / 100)
}
```

Comment: Ok, but any idea why I cannot move the `@@ Sorted` into a later evidence parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to make the Sorted tag be part of the type signature of the implicit class, the way you have it now, you are looking for some implicit value which is tagged with Sorted, but you don't have an implicit value anywhere, you just have an implicit conversion from `IndexedSeq` to `RichIndexedSeq`.  Here's what I'd suggest:

```
implicit final class RichSortedIndexedSeq[AA, CC[_] <: IndexedSeq[_]](val sq: CC[AA] @@ Sorted) 
  extends AnyVal {

  /** Nearest percentile (rounded index, no interpolation). */
  def percentile(n: Int): AA =
    sq((sq.size * n - 50) / 100)
}
```

And I bleieve this SHOULD work, however, this seems to expose a compiler bug.  When I leave the return type of percentile explicitly declared, I get this compiler error:

```
/tmp/sorted.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: AA
    sq((sq.size * n - 50) / 100)
      ^
one error found
```

We can tell this is an error because it is looking for a type named A, but we haven't talked about such a type anywhere, this is a compiler error where the type variable of IndexedSeq is somehow leaking out.  This seems to be a manifestation of [this bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7944) which has since been fixed, but I'm not sure what released versions (if any) of scalac contain the fix.

Comment: Ok, so this is the same idea as Kenji. He left away the return type of `percentile` and that seems to compile. The type mismatch you (and I) encounter is extremely weird!?

Comment: yeah, but if you leave the return type off then try to do anything with the result, it will not compile.  Like take your Seq of Ints, call percentile, then try to add 1 to the result.  It will be trying to do any2stringadd with a mysterious A type instead of an integer add with an Int.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong place. Here:

```
implicit final class RichIndexedSeq[A, 
  CC <: IndexedSeq[A]] // This A is *NOT INFERRED* from the previous one
  (val sq: CC)
```

There's nothing in there that leads to the inference of `A`, and that's what causes the problem. See here:

```
scala> new RichIndexedSeq(y)
<console>:19: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,@@[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],Sorted]] do not conform to class R
ichIndexedSeq's type parameter bounds [A,CC <: IndexedSeq[A]]
              new RichIndexedSeq(y)
              ^
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : @@[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int],Sorted]
    (which expands to)  scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] with AnyRef{type Tag = Sorted}
 required: CC
              new RichIndexedSeq(y)
                                 ^
```

And, in fact, let's try it with `x`:

```
scala> new RichIndexedSeq(x)
<console>:16: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] do not conform to class RichIndexedS
eq's type parameter bounds [A,CC <: IndexedSeq[A]]
              new RichIndexedSeq(x)
              ^
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
 required: CC
              new RichIndexedSeq(x)
                                 ^
```

And, now, let's be explicit about the type parameter:

```
scala> new RichIndexedSeq[Int, @@[Vector[Int], Sorted]](y)
res6: RichIndexedSeq[Int,@@[Vector[Int],Sorted]] = RichIndexedSeq@1a925d98
```

And testing it:

```
scala> res6.percentile(50)
res8: Int = 49
```

To solve this kind of type inference problem there's a trait called `IsTraversableLike`. Unfortunately, its usage seems to be at odd with the need to preserve the tag, but I suggest you read it up -- you might find a way to do it, or you might write a similar trait that serves your needs.